# MySql SELECT, check if record has different value in Status then use one

Tags: mysql, case-when

I have this table of orders and statuses:

```
id   |   date          |   status
123    2015-12-01           order
123    2015-12-20           refund
234    2015-12-21           order
456    2015-12-22           order
456    2015-12-22           refund
```

Now I'd like to get results on 'status' column that whenever the ID also has a status of 'refund' then use this value instead of value 'order'.

As follows:

```
id   |   date        |   status    | refund_date
123    2015-12-01         refund      2015-12-20
234    2015-12-21         order
456    2015-12-22         refund      2015-12-22
```

I have this query that retrieves the refund_date but I'm unsure how to get the status for refund orders. Additionally the table has like 500k records so performance is a key.

```
select 
    id,
    date,
    status,
    case when count(id)>1 then max(date) else min(date) end as refund_date
from orders
group by id
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `union all` for this purpose:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.status = 'refund'
union all
select o.*
from orders o
where o.status = 'order' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders o2
                  where o2.id = o.id and o2.status = 'refund'
                 );
```

With indexes on `orders(status)` and `orders(id, status)`, this query should be quite fast.

Comment: 3 points: 1) why use union when I only want to return each order once showing the 'refund' status where applicable. 2) the refund orders are queried twice. 3) duration/fetch time is: 31 sec / 600 sec with lost connection error on 200k records. Or maybe im doing something wrong?

Comment: Okay Gordon never mind i missed the last line to index, now its running in blazing speeds in 2 sec and returns results as desired. Still need to study why.... Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Join an "order" view of the table with a "refund" view of the table. Use coalesce, which is a function that evaluates to the first non-null argument, to identify the status.

```
select t1.id, t1.date, coalesce(t2.status, t1.status), t2.date 
from orders t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t2.status = 'refund')
where t1.status = 'order'
```

Comment: Willis, thank you works great as well. Actually I realized some refunds are only partially refunded or only shipping charge refunds but the core order still intact, so is it possible to join on t1.price [=> 50% then] t2.price ? Tnx. I chose 50% because i think that might be a threshold